# Could someone explain the following Ruby on Rails error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

LoadError in CandidatesController#create

> Unable to autoload constant `Usermailer`, expected `Z:/railsassignment/student/app/mailers/usermailer.rb` to define it

When I submit a form I get the error above. The form processes a record and the candidate is added to the database however the welcome email I'm trying to send to the newly registered candidate doesn't send, and the error above prevents the user from proceeding.

**Candidates Controller**

```
def create
  @candidate = Candidate.new(candidate_params)

 respond_to do |format|
   if @candidate.save
     Usermailer.welcome(@candidate).deliver_now ***<-- Error highlights this line***
     format.html { redirect_to @candidate, notice: 'User was successfully    
   created.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @candidate }
    else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @candidate.errors, status:   
 :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

**usermailer.rb**

Z:/railsassignment/student/app/mailers/usermailer.rb (usermailer directory)

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "from@example.com"

def welcome(candidate)
 @candidate = candidate
 mail(:to => candidate.can_email, :subject => "Welcome to EmployeMe.com, You    
 have registered successfully!")
 end
end
```

Should you need to see any more of the files drop me a comment and I'll be quick to add them to the question.

Comment: `Usermailer` != `UserMailer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a case of messed up naming convention.

As per `Rails` naming convention, *file names* should be in `snake_case` and *class names* in `CamelCase`. In your scenario, the file name should be `user_mailer.rb`.

So either rename `usermailer.rb` to `user_mailer.rb` 
or
class name `UserMailer` to `Usermailer`.

Comment: Either `Usermailer` and `usermailer.rb`, or `UserMailer` and `user_mailer.rb`.

Comment: So when I change usermailer.rb to user_mailer.rb the follwing error occurs:                                                                                                 NameError in CandidatesController#create
uninitialized constant CandidatesController::Usermailer.                                         It refers to the same line highlighted in the original Q.

Comment: And when I change Usermailer to UserMailer I get the following error: Template is missing
Missing template user_mailer/welcome with "mailer". Searched in: * "user_mailer".

Comment: @Charlie, please use the generators to create your files and don't edit class names and such.  Then you won't have this problem.  As for your followup questions here, it's all related.  You have to pick a name and then make it consistent everywhere - declarations, usages, file names, and directory name on the views.  If you're testing, you'll have to make changes in the test structure, too.  Please do that before asking more.

Comment: @Charlie: please make sure you call the mailer method properly i,e `UserMailer.welcome` in your candidates_controller.rb

Comment: i ended up destroying the whole mailer object and generated it again after nothing worked it works fine now thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

**Always use snake case for your file names.**

```
Z:/railsassignment/student/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
```

**NOT:**

```
Z:/railsassignment/student/app/mailers/usermailer.rb
```

**Always use camel case for your class names**

```
UserMailer.welcome(@candidate).deliver_now
```

**NOT:**

```
Usermailer.welcome(@candidate).deliver_now
```

If your interested in how constants loading works with rails you could take a gander at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).